# Why is it bad practice to use Symbols in actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have some action types in my app that I've declared like this:

```
export const TICTACTOE_PLAY = Symbol();
export const TICTACTOE_RESET = Symbol();
```

Then I wrote some action dispatchers like this:

```
export const play = coordinates => ({ type: TICTACTOE_PLAY, coordinates });
export const reset = () => ({ type: TICTACTOE_RESET });
```

I prefer symbols over strings because they are primitive, I believe them to be faster to compare than strings (in the reducer), and they can't collide with each other.

However in the [Redux style guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions) I read that this was an anti-pattern. However, I can't fully understand this sentence:

> This ensures that capabilities such as debugging via the Redux
> DevTools will work as expected. It also ensures that the UI will
> update as expected.

Why would non-serializable values like symbols prevent Redux DevTools or UI to work as expected? I understand that it may not help debugging, I understand that the state has to be serializable (for use cases like server-side rendering) but I don't get why actions have to be serializable.

Comment: It says in big letters "**Do Not Put Non-Serializable Values in State or Actions**". Well, symbols are not serialisable.

Comment: My guess is that they are serialised. It does say that you can use non-serialisable values only if you are planning on cancelling the action. So, it's an educated guess. I'm not really very familiar with Redux aside from the basics.

Comment: Because the redux devtool as an chrome extension relies on `window.postMessage` API to communicate with your app. That API would serialize any value before send it across process. So if you use symbol type, the message cannot be deserialize/restored on the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the particular case you're asking about of why it might break Redux DevTools, there seems to be a [section in the FAQ](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants) about this.

> As with state, serializable actions enable several of Redux's defining features, such as time travel debugging, and recording and replaying actions. Using something like a Symbol for the type value or using instanceof checks for actions themselves would break that.